# Unable to connect to Oracle database using instance_name

Tags: database, oracle

I'm able to connect to database by using service_name in connection string but not using instance name. When I use instance_name I get the below error.

ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connection descriptor

when I try to connect to DB from host after setting ORACLE_SID it is not connecting

```
[oracle@OfflineRep ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Aug 28 15:25:22 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.
```

But connects when I deliberately use SID

```
[oracle@OfflineRep ~]$ sqlplus sys/***************@sid as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Aug 28 15:26:05 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to connect from a 11.2.0.1.0 Oracle home using sqlplus / as sysdba but the database is on an 11.2.0.4.0 home. You may need to set your ORACLE_HOME variable to point to the Oracle home that the database uses and to put $ORACLE_HOME/bin in your path after setting ORACLE_HOME to the database's 11.2.0.4.0 home.